# low storage after installation of chrx on chromebook

Tags: linux, command-line, storage, chromebook

so today i tried to install chrx on my chromebook. i executed the command `cd ; curl -Os https://chrx.org/go && sh go` and it prompted me to enter an amount of storage it wanted me to have it save. it recommended 23gb and my chromebook comes with 32. so i entered 23. it accepted, then the whole chromebook shut off and turned back on, and "repaired" itself. when i went to the process again i got a message that said "low storage, please remove some files to free up space." and i clicked on the popup and it said i only had 1.4 gb of storage when i know i clearly had 32gb, can you help me fix my problem please?

Comment: You have 32 GB of total system space.  How much free space did you think you had?

Comment: I suggest you remove `chrx`, including settings, then reinstall with less disc space. I suggest you don't allocate more than half your disc to it. You might be better to investigate whether you can upgrade your disc.

Comment: well i think i had about 28.5gb

Comment: AFH i fixed this problem